# IN() not working - MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have this simple query -:

```
SET @rejects = "'song1','song2'"; 
SELECT * FROM media WHERE share_src IS NULL || share_src NOT IN(@rejects)
```

But this doesn't work, and also shows the rows with `share_src = song1` and `share_src = song2`.

What is the trouble in my query. Thanks for help..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a version for *dynamic sql*

```
SET @rejects = "'song1','song2'"; 
SET @sql = NULL;

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT * 
                    FROM media 
                    WHERE share_src IS NULL OR share_src NOT IN(',@rejects,')');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Comment: There an error in this query -: `1243 - Unknown prepared statement handler (stmt) given to EXECUTE`

Comment: When i eliminate the last `DEALLOCATE` statement, the error doesn't come

Answer (score 1):

`IN` does not work with *one* string. You have either use really comma separated values and not just one string or use a *Prepared Statement*.

That works:

```
SELECT * FROM media 
WHERE share_src IS NULL || share_src NOT IN('song1', 'song2')
```

but that doesn't

```
SELECT * FROM media 
WHERE share_src IS NULL || share_src NOT IN("'song1','song2'")
```

Comment: Can you give an example , how do i do it using prepared statement

Comment: @RayZ: See JW's answer for that.

Answer (score 0):

you are treating this as all one string.

you would have to execute the entire statement as a string instead...
(in Oracle `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE`)

Answer (score 0):

Try with find_in_set function

```
SET @rejects = "song1,song2"; 
SELECT * FROM media WHERE share_src IS NULL ||  NOT FIND_IN_SET(share_src, @rejects)
```